# Reiniciar uma calculadora em python

Tags: python

Então gente, eu estou começando agora em python e eu fiz uma calculadora bem simples. Só inserir a operação, o primeiro e o segundo número, que ele mostra o resultado. Eu consegui elaborar um método para fechar o script, mas eu queria fazer com que ele iniciasse novamente se tn == 's'.

```
tn = input('Tentar novamente? (s/n)')
if tn != 's':
  print(quit)
  quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma bem simples seria usar loop com While:

```
while True:
    tn = input('Tentar novamente? (s/n)')
    if tn != 's':
        break
```